# Formulário de contato com textarea ao lado dos inputs

Tags: html, css

Quero colocar o formulário de contato com os *`inputs`* ao lado esquerdo e o *`textarea`* ao lado direito conforme na imagem abaixo, consigo fazer o resultado esperado com o *`float:left`* porém assim o meu layout acaba quebrando.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como conseguir o resultado esperado sem o *`float`*?

Segue o código que utilizei:

```css
.contact{
  float: left;
  width: 49.5%;
}

input, textarea{
  border: 1px solid lightblue;
  width: 100%;
}

textarea{
  height: 65px;
  resize: none;
}

.left{
  margin-right: .5%;
}

.right{
  margin-left: .5%;
}
```

```html
  <div class="contact left">
    <input type="text" name="nome" autocomplete="name" placeholder="Nome" required>
    <input type="text" name="empresa" autocomplete="organization" placeholder="Empresa">
    <input type="text" name="telefone" autocomplete="tel-national" placeholder="Telefone" required>
  </div>
  <div class="contact right">
    <textarea name="mensagem" placeholder="Mensagem" required></textarea>   </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Faz com Flexbox que por default já coloca um elemento ao lado do outro.

Vc nem vai notar a diferença. parece que ainda está com `float`, mas só precisei colocar todo o conteúdo dentro de uma div e colocar o `display:flex` **OBS:** coloquei `box-sizing:border-box` para o valor das bordas não se somarem e vc ficar com uma barra de rolagem horizontal indesejada na página

Veja como ficou o resultado.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
html, body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.forme {
  display: flex;
}
.contact{
  width: 49.5%;
}
input, textarea{
  border: 1px solid lightblue;
  width: 100%;
}
textarea{
  height: 65px;
  resize: none;
}
.left{
  margin-right: .5%;
}
.right{
  margin-left: .5%;
}
```

```html
<div class="forme">
  <div class="contact left">
    <input type="text" name="nome" autocomplete="name" placeholder="Nome" required>
    <input type="text" name="empresa" autocomplete="organization" placeholder="Empresa">
    <input type="text" name="telefone" autocomplete="tel-national" placeholder="Telefone" required>
  </div>
  <div class="contact right">
    <textarea name="mensagem" placeholder="Mensagem" required></textarea>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Boa, como mantenho o CSS e removo essa barra de rolagem inferior?

Comment: @LaércioLopes editei a resposta, olha lá a **OBS**

Comment: Perfeito, vou aceitar assim que permitir. Obrigado.

Comment: Se quiser colocar margem na direita e esquerda use a sua classe .contact que fica bom tb.

Comment: @LaércioLopes Vlw jovem!